# What is the right place for user-defined init.m?

Tags: initialization

What is the right folder to put a file init.m which will be run after all other `init.m` files applied by the various components of *Mathematica* have done their job?

I would like to use it to do something like

```
 AppendTo[$Path, *my favourite place*];
 Unprotect[Needs];
 Needs[x_] := Needs[x, ContextToFileName[x]]; 
 Protect[Needs]; 
 Needs["CleanSlate`"];
 SetOptions[FileNames, IgnoreCase->True];
 ClearAttributes[If, HoldAll]; SetAttributes[If, HoldRest];
 ClearAttributes[Switch,HoldAll]; SetAttributes[Switch, HoldRest];
 Unprotect[RGBColor]; 
 RGBColor[{x_, y_, z_}] := RGBColor[x, y, z]; 
 Protect[RGBColor];
 Unprotect[MantissaExponent]; 
 MantissaExponent[i_?IntegerQ] := MantissaExponent[1.*i]
 Protect[MantissaExponent];
```

... and other things which make my work go smoother.

Previously (in Version 4.0)

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\4.0\AddOns\Autoload\init.m
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\4.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\init.m
```

were the right places for this type of operations.

Comment: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Kernel","init.m"}]`

Comment: Dupe? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16401/user-defined-functions-how-to-save-them-for-future-use/16402#16402

Answer (score 22):

There are two typical locations where a user can add an `init.m` file to be loaded at run-time: `$BaseDirectory` and `$UserBaseDirectory`. `$BaseDirectory` is useful for installation wide customizations that apply to all users while `$UserBaseDirectory` is used for a specific users customizations. So, anything in `$UserBaseDirectory` is loaded after the files found in `$BaseDirectory` so that the user's preferences are heeded. For most users, this distinction is likely not to matter as they are the only user of their computer.  However, I would recommend using `$UserBaseDirectory` as it is less messy, and it provides you with several opportunities for customization. From this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html) on the system file layout, there are two locations where a global `init.m` will be picked up on load:

- `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Kernel"}]`
- `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"FrontEnd"}]`

where an `init.m` file will be loaded when the respective component is loaded (kernel or front-end).  The subdirectories in `$UserBaseDirectory` is also where your custom style-sheets would go, but that is off topic for the question.

Comment: Files in `$UserBaseDirectory` will (should) also remain when you uninstall *Mathematica* or upgrade versions.  They are also simpler to back-up.

Comment: But FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"FrontEnd"}] is the one, which is rewritten on every start of Mathematica. This is certainly not the right place to store any customization!

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen yes and no. My take on it is that the FE reads in init.m, and then spits out a modified version based upon what has changed during the session. In fact, if it finds stuff in it doesn’t recognize, it will assume it is corrupt and replace it with the default version which can be a bit disconcerting upon opening. However, the settings within the `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,...]` can be modified, and they are respected. So, it looks like you’re limited to the FrontEnd Options.

Answer (score 1):

The place given by `$UserBaseDirectory` or by `$UserDirectory` did not work for me in Version 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016).

But adding a file init.m to `C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel` worked for me.

To test it, I defined a variable and assigned it a value and checked it in the subsequent Mathematica session: It was defined and had the right value.