# A global setting for the directory path

Tags: files-and-directories

I want a global setting for Mathematica that changes the default directory to the current folder where the Mathematica's file therein. When I want to change the directory to the current folder, I use `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` command at the top of my code to change the directory. Is there any global setting in Mathematica that changes the directory to a current folder where the Mathematica file exists there?

Comment: The problem is that you can open the notebook without starting the kernel. And current directory is a kernel's setting. You / the FrontEnd can also start the kernel without any particular notebook or with a non saved notebook. So there are many 'buts' with `SetDirectory` when Mathematica starts.
Shortly, you can edit `init.m` file but `NotebookDirectory[]` may not be available and you will often get annoying messges.

Comment: Dear @Kuba, If want to apply `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` command when the kernel starts, what shall I do?

Comment: You can append it to your Kernel/init.m file, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63741/5478

Comment: The problem is that there is no `NotebookDirectory[]` when the kernel starts.  As an example create a new notebook without saving it and issue the `SetDirectory` command and you will see what I mean.