# Adding new functions globally

Tags: functions, core-language

Perhaps this is bad practice, but I'm wondering if it's possible to create my own Mathematica functions and make them equivalent to core functions (i.e they are available in any notebook/kernel session automatically)

Comment: You should put the function definitions in your kernel init file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [user defined functions, how to save them for future use?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16401/user-defined-functions-how-to-save-them-for-future-use)